# TFS 2017 MSBuild SingTool not found for Clickonce

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, signtool

I recently moved my TFS to a new server.
After installing everything and setting up a new Agent my builds got the following error:

> Error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe was not found at path \signtool.exe.

On my other server (Running VS 2015 and TFS 17 RC) everything worked like a charm.
I then made sure Visual studio 2017 also installed the Windows 10 SDK because in the Developer command prompt typing: 'where signtool' didn't work.
But now it does: [image: Signtool available]

My TFS build still gives me this error.
It's weird that the path is to my Application solution folder and not the signtool actual location.

Does anybody have any idea on what this issue might be?

Comment: Which build are you running XAML build or vNnext build?

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have installed the related  .NET Framework. Take a look at this similar question: [An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2013/11/18/an-error-occurred-while-signing-signtool-exe-not-found/)

Try to build locally in your build agent to see if you still got the same error.

If the build is successful locally, suggest you reconfigure or reinstall the build agents. The build agent will not detect the environment changes after you installed it. It will only detect during the installation. If you are using vNext build agent, also try to manually add some capabilities in ***Settings- Agent Queues- Agent Pool - Agent- Capabilities***. After this trigger the build again.